# using Ubuntu commands in php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, command

Is it possible to use ***ubuntu terminal commands*** in *php* program.for example i need to create a folder and compress (.zip) it using php program. How to code this need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a host of commands you can use, `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `passthru()`, `system()` just to name a few.  Just remember, if you intend to let this anywhere even remotely near user input (Even for uploaded files) you should use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) or [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).  In fact, just read [this whole section of the PHP Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php) first.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you're after [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Answer (score 5):

The better way to do this is by using the [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

exec will be useful for that case, but be careful, don't let user to run those commands.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [system()](http://www.php.net/system)

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to put your command between `` `(not ' ' or " " ),` is shift+tilda(~) for example you can use :

```
echo "<pre>".`ls -alh`;
```

Comment: Which is identical to shell_exec()